# How to make an image escape/extend the container for a full-width section with one side reaching the edge?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm working on a web project and trying to create a full-width section with an image that extends beyond its container. Specifically, I want one side of the image to go all the way to the edge of the screen while keeping the rest of the content inside a container (max-width).

Here's the relevant part of my HTML and CSS code:

```
<section class="full-width-split-screen">
    <div class="accent">
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="c--fhd mx-auto">
                <div class="wrapper mx-auto">
                    <div class="hero__flex d-flex f-c pos-rel extra">
                        <div class="hero__content h-100">
                            <div class="w-100 mx-auto d-flex f-c">
                                <div class="hero__header d-flex f-c">
                                    <h1 class="f-700 hero__header-text-first">
                                        <?php echo $firstHeader; ?>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img class="hero__img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/hero-image.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It's really hard for me to just put an fragment of CSS code, I'm pretty sure there's a lot of errors, but I was doing my best. Here's fragment but probably you will want to use whole .css file: https://pastebin.com/ffLxhvbM

```
#{$hero}, #{$heroContact} {
  &__content {
    flex: 1 0 50%;
    @media (max-width: 1260px) {
      flex: 1 0 100%;
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      flex: 1 0 75%;
    }
    @media (max-width: 540px) {
      flex: 1 0 90%;
    }
  }
}

.full-width-split-screen > :not(img) {
  padding-inline: var(--wrapper-padding-inline);
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .full-width-split-screen {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:
      minmax(var(--wrapper-padding-inline), 1fr)
      minmax(0, calc(var(--wrapper-max-width) / 2))
      minmax(0, calc(var(--wrapper-max-width) / 2))
      minmax(var(--wrapper-padding-inline), 1fr);
    position: relative;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-column: 2 / -1;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img):first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > img:first-child {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > img:last-child {
    grid-column: 2 / -1;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img) {
    display: grid !important;
    align-content: center !important;
    justify-items: start !important;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img):last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img)::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background: inherit;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img):last-child::before {
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
  }
}

.hero__img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

At this moment the image is not extended, it's still inside of the container that have max-width on it. I want this image to extend the container, the proportion, here's image:

Note: `max-width` is really necessary to keep the page with the same margin, our wrapper is used on every section (not header and footer).

[image: design-]

I've already tried creating grid, `::before`, and others, even `flex: 0 0 50%` wasn't that bad, but I'm searching for a more robust and modern solution.